# Meteor stream not working until browser page refreshed

Tags: javascript, meteor, redis

I am using streams to send notification between two applications. The applications are communicating through clusters via redis. Whenever, I push some notification from one app to another, it does not work. But when I refresh the browsers and try, it works.

Can u please tell me what is the problem. My code goes as follows:

App 1 code

```
function sendMessage(message,date,toUserId,fromUserId,jobId){
  ChatStream.emit(toUserId,message,date,toUserId,fromUserId,jobId);
}

ChatStream.on(Meteor.userId(),function(message,date,toUserId,fromUserId,jobId){
  var formatDate = moment(date).fromNow();
  var index = ClientChat.find().count();
  var chatObj = {
    from:fromUserId,
    message:message,
    date:formatDate,
    jobId:jobId,
    index:index
  }
  //ClientChat.insert({from:fromUserId,message:message,date:formatDate,jobId:jobId,index:index})
  ClientChat.insert(chatObj);
  Session.set('receivedPing',chatObj);
})
```

App2

```
function sendMessage(message,date,toUserId,fromUserId,jobId){
  ChatStream.emit(toUserId,message,date,toUserId,fromUserId,jobId);
}

ChatStream.on(Meteor.userId(),function(message,date,toUserId,fromUserId,jobId){
  ClientChat.insert({from:fromUserId,message:message,date:date,jobId:jobId})
})
```

Cluster.js in server folder

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Meteor.Cluster.init();
  Meteor.Cluster.sync(ChatStream,LocalNotificationStream);
})
```

lib folder

```
ChatStream = new Meteor.Stream('chatStream');
```

The packages I am using are of arunoda streams
http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/

Comment: the cause can be because you run only on server. you should also make it available for client

Comment: u mean to make cluster.js available on both client and server? If so, why is it working after I refresh the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. This was because, the code

```
ChatStream.on(Meteor.userId(),function(message,date,toUserId,fromUserId,jobId){
  ClientChat.insert({from:fromUserId,message:message,date:date,jobId:jobId})
})
```

was running when the app just started and when the user had not logged in. So i made sure to run this code only when the user is logged in by doing this

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  if(Meteor.userId()){
         ChatStream.on(Meteor.userId(),function(message,date,toUserId,fromUserId,jobId){
      ClientChat.insert({from:fromUserId,message:message,date:date,jobId:jobId})
    })   
      }
    })
  }
});
```